# Changing default /submit route in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

The **Discover Meteor** book develops a sample appliction called Microscope, with the Github repo here: https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope

In it, the submit form seems to be defaulted (as nowhere can a see a link to /submit in the html).

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>

Router.route('/submit', {name: 'postSubmit'});
```

How can I call this something else, eg: /postSubmit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you could change the route path to `/postSubmit`

```
Router.route('/postSubmit', {name: 'postSubmit'});
```

This works because the code is using `pathFor`, which takes the path name provided (`postSubmit`) to look up the corresponding route path (`/postSubmit`).

For the example below the `href` will be substituted with `/postSubmit`

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'postSubmit'}}">Submit Post</a>
```

and the outcome will be:

```
<a href="/postSubmit">Submit Post</a>
```